# How to customize searchBar scope

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

So I have been searching everywhere, but can't come to an answer on this. I have a UISearchBar searchBar setup that filters my data. I came across scope functionality, but created my own scope buttons. So my question is, how do I link those buttons I made so that they can perform the same thing as UISearchBar scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope buttons are more a convenience than anything else. They don't automatically change the scope of the search. That is something you have to do in response to the user changing the scope.

Normally, you don't make the buttons yourself. You set the titles for the buttons in the `scopeButtonTitles` property of the search bar, e.g.:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Scope 1", "Scope 2"]
```

and then in the `UISearchBarDelegate` delegate implement

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
```

to act upon the user's choice.

But if there's a great reason to make your own buttons, you just do it all yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fully understand that, but I already have buttons fully customized with animations and everything that I want to use instead of the buttons that are supplied when using "self.searchController.searBar.scopeButtonTitles"

Comment: If you could get your buttons to appear in the right place then this would be solved for you?

Comment: It's more of getting my buttons to achieve what scope buttons can

Comment: They don't really achieve anything other than presenting UI. In my code, when `searchBar(_:, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)` is called, I change the search I'm doing on the database.

Comment: From Apple's documentation of `UISearchBarDelegate`:

A UISearchBar object provides the user interface for a search field on a bar, but it’s the application’s responsibility to implement the actions when buttons are tapped. At a minimum, the delegate needs to perform the actual search when text is entered in the text field.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a very brief example? I'm having a bit of difficulty in understanding how exactly to hook everything up

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial is a pretty good tutorial on using `UISearchController`s with a table view. There's a section on adding a scope bar and you'll find that it just results in one extra call on the delegate `searchBar(_:, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)` where the work of making the scope change do something is done. The UI components don't do any of the work. It's completely up to you to implement having a scope change do something meaningful.

Comment: Alright  thank you for the help, I wasn't aware the call to the extra delegate

Comment: making so I followed the link but I reached a wall, any chance you can help out ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153579/custom-scope-buttons?noredirect=1#comment73383757_43153579