# Custom scope buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to create custom scope buttons, but i'm having trouble actually linking them to my buttons. This is what I have

```
extension HomeViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = titles[searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)

}
}
extension HomeViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: titles[selectedScope] )
}
}
```

This is the array that I was using to pass the category in which to search for from my function

```
 var titles = [String]()

func firstFunc(){
titles = ["Pizza"]
}

 func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredCandies = candies.filter { candy in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All")||(candy.Food == scope)
        return categoryMatch && candy.Calories.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: So I have buttons created that have the same purpose of a searchBar scope, so following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial it says to create searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = "", but because I want to use my own buttons I created var titles = [String]() , which is what I use in both extensions. In my function "firstFunc" I set the String that is inside my array to "Pizza" in hopes of that is what will be passed in my extensions and change the data inside of "candy", but nothing happens